# Is it possible for Herr Kleiser to die?

Tags: marvel, ultimates

In the Ultimates, Herr Kleiser seems pretty much indestructible, since he does not really have a true physical form until he takes someone's body over. Even when he is eaten by the Hulk, they have to contain the Hulk's waste so that Herr Kleiser does not get out again. Is there any way that he can be killed for good?

Answer (score 2):

It is unknown. He has no further appearances after being eaten in *The Ultimates*. It is worth noting that they took The Hulk's excrement for analysis and containment as a matter of caution, because they were uncertain if Herr Kleiser was actually dead, not because they knew that he had survived the experience.

[image: Hulk excrement containment - The Ultimates Vol 1 - # 13] (click to enlarge)

> Nick Fury: "Just a little security measure, soldier: The Hulk beat Kleiser by chewing him up and **digesting** him, right? Well, Kleiser being a shape-changer and all, let's just say that we have to catch whatever comes out of the other end and lock it up with all the **other** little leftovers we captured."

Comment: Well, that sounds pretty crappy